# Need Apache Camel to invoke a custom processor every 10 minutes in the background

Tags: apache-camel, background-process

We are using Apache Camel in our project catering to multiple endpoints like REST, SFTP, SOAP etc. This is invoked as part of  scheduled jobs which can sometimes run for hours if there are too many records to process.
There are times, when our job ( or rather the flow) gets stuck for hours on any of the camel route.
Our requirement is to terminate such long running/stuck jobs.
So, what we are looking for is that once we start a job using context.start(), create a custom processor which can be invoked every X minutes.
In that custom processor we will  write custom logic whether to continue or terminate the job etc.

Do we have any such mechanism in Camel to write a custom processor which can be triggered by Camel frequently within the primary running Camel Context?
Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use [Camel's timer component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html) to run a task on a fixed interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another Camel Route that is triggered periodically and calls your processor. For the periodic trigger you can choose from multiple components.

- [Camel Timer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html) > No dependencies, but most primitive, based on JDK Timer)
- [Camel Scheduler](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/scheduler-component.html) > No dependencies, more options, based on ScheduledExecutorService)
- [Camel Quartz](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quartz-component.html) > Needs camel-quartz, loads of options, supports Cron expressions
- [Camel Cron](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/cron-component.html) > Only in Camel 3, supports Cron expressions

Comment: Our requirement is to interrupt the primary context at scheduled interval and resume the job.   Main objective is while the job is running we will receive the interrupt signal from another service.  We have the custom processor in place which will verify and act on interrupt signal after processing each route.  If the job stucks at any particular route , it is not responding to interrupt signal. Thats why we want to check the interrupt signal at scheduled interval.